# What is a good resource to learn Ruby for a Seasoned c# developer?

Tags: c#, ruby

I'm a long time c# developer who recently took a job that primarily uses Ruby as a way to force myself to become proficient with another language.

Any suggestions as to a good C# -> Ruby resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the Code Camp recording here: http://www.slideshare.net/CoryFoy/ruby-for-c-developers

or

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-c-and-c-/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A tip: forget everything about C# when programming Ruby. They are completely different beasts.

The best Ruby book/resource/tutorial I've ever read is the [Pickaxe](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0). I'm a pretty experiences Ruby dev, and I still regularly reference it.

Plus, it includes a full reference to all of the Ruby stdlib and builtin classes.

**Warning:** it will set you back about 50-60 USD.

Comment: I highly recommend getting the PDF or electronic versions of the book. You can store a copy on your smart phone or a tablet, plus your home and work computer, so the reference is always available.

Answer (score 0):

I came from C, C++ & C# (1.0 - 3.5) and there's one book that stood out for me:  -http://humblelittlerubybook.com/ (and it's free)

NB./ it covers an older version of Ruby 1.8, but there's not that much new with 1.9 & 2.0.

I <3 Ruby now :)